# React Class component updates the value for class variable in re-render but not the Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I was playing with ***ReacJS***. I noticed a thing- 
In case of **Class Component** during *re-rendering* class variable's updated value is updated in screen like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Temp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.count = 0;
    this.state = {
      foo: 0,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          this.setState({ foo: this.state.foo + 1 });
          this.count++;
        }}
      >
        {this.count} - {this.state.foo}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default Temp;
```

But in case of **function componen**t the updated value of the ordinary variable is not updated in the screen during *re-rendering*.

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

const RefComponent = () => {
  const [stateNumber, setStateNumber] = useState(0);
  let refVar = 0;

  function incrementAndDelayedLogging() {
    setStateNumber(stateNumber + 1);
    refVar++;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={incrementAndDelayedLogging}>Click</button>
      <h4>state: {stateNumber}</h4>
      <h4>refVar: {refVar}</h4>
    </div>
  );
};

export default RefComponent;
```

Is this how React was implemented or I'm messing around something? I'm curious to know about it.
Thanks

Comment: Every time functional RefComponent is rendered (called) it executes `let refVar = 0;` so refVar is created every time you render. You could do: `const refVar = React.useRef(0);` then `refVar.current++` and `<h4>refVar: {refVar.current}</h4>`

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm familiar with useRef, actually I'm not searching for the way to solve this rather i just wanted to know why it happens in this way. But i appreciate your replies. Another query, doesn't class component gets called like the function component?

Comment: No, a functional component is just a function returning jsx, a class component is a class (in JavaScript also just a function but called as `new MyClass()`). So `name` in class component is an instance property (also called member), and name in functional component is just a variable you set every time it is called.

Answer (score 2):

Functional components in React don't have instances, so things like class or instance variables don't necessarily make sense; like others have pointed out in the comments here, React will render (call) functional components and "reset" any local variables that are not explicitly state. [Behavior like instance variables for functional components are achieved with `useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables).

From the docs:

> The `useRef()` Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose `current` property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of functional components.

Think about it like this: Each time a state var is updated or a prop is updated your function gets called again. All variable declaration will happen again (states are a special case), so `let refVar = 0;` gets called again.

If you need that variable to live for multiple renders you'll need to declare it in a context that survives re-renders.

You have at least 2 ways of achieving this

- declare a state for it with `useState`
- declare it at the module level, but know all your instances of `RefComponent` will share the same instance

Comment: You could do useRef, then you can change it without the component re rendering just as an instance variable of a class would behave.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm familiar with useRef, actually I'm not searching for the way to solve this rather i just wanted to know why it happens in this way. But I appreciate your replies. Another query, doesn't class component gets called like the function component?

Comment: @Mateen It seems you're not familiar with constructor functions (JS doesn't have classes but protype and constructor functions). A class component is a [constructor function with prototype](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) and is used like `new Component().render()` and a functional component is just called `jsx=Component(props)`

Comment: Sorry, I do know that Classes are just syntactic sugar over how we dealt with prototype chain of function, and later with new keyword. But I failed to match that here. What I asked all was about mechanism of React's rendering. Now I got it. Thanks.